# Implement reversing a sequence in a way that is idiomatic for Clojure

Tags: clojure

The task is to write a function that reverses a sequence. I am trying to do this as efficiently and clojure-ish as possible, but I can't figure out the best way. It doesn't feel right to create a variable and start appending items to that variable.  What would seem idiomatic to me was if there was a way to do the following:

From the Clojure docs

```
(map-indexed (fn [idx itm] [idx itm]) "foobar")
--> ([0 \f] [1 \o] [2 \o] [3 \b] [4 \a] [5 \r])
```

What I have done is this:

```
(defn testing [x]
(map-indexed (fn [idx itm] [(- (count x) idx) itm]) x))
```

Which yields:

```
(testing "foobar")
--> ([6 \f] [5 \o] [4 \o] [3 \b] [2 \a] [1 \r])
```

What I can't figure out is how to essentially pack that back up into a new list with the correct indexes. Honestly, even the concept of declaring a variable is escaping me in Clojure at the moment. All my experience is with Python and Ruby.

Comment: You can find the source code of `reverse` at http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reverse#source.

Comment: Can I suggest that you re-title the question "Implement reversing a sequence in a way that is idiomatic for Clojure". The idiomatic way to return a sequence in general is usually lazily, but that isn't the case for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are sequable so we can use [clojure.core/reduce](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce)

```
(defn rev [x]
  (reduce #(str %2 %1) x))

(rev "foobar") ;; "raboof"
```

The idea is that for each iteration, we create a new string that is the next character in the sequence prepended to the current string.

> *All my experience is with Python and Ruby*

Here is the same in `Ruby`:

```
def rev(x)
  x.chars.reduce { |s, c| c + s }
end
```

For non-strings

```
(defn rev [x]
  (reduce conj () x))

(rev [1 2 3 4 5]) ;; (5 4 3 2 1)
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks much!  I knew this was one of those things that would be simple even though I was over here banging my head against the wall.

Comment: Actually @Kyle , for some reason I'm having an equal amount of trouble making this work with a seq that isn't a string.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Borromakot I added a solution for non-strings. If you were to use this with a string you may want to `(apply str (rev "foobar"))` to get a string as output.

Comment: Thanks!  Great stuff.  I was looking in the entirely wrong place.  I had assumed that I was just trying to connect the two, using concat or conj or something along those lines.  Didn't even know about cons.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse a sequence using indexes, as your question proposes, as follows:

```
(defn reverse [s]
  (let [v (vec s)] (map v (range (dec (count v)) -1 -1))))
```

... or, perversely,

```
(def reverse (comp rseq vec))
```